# How to extract the the alt value form a jsx image element?

Tags: reactjs

I have this logic where I want to get the alt attribute value of an image element, my first idea way to simply make the value of the key and array that holds a string and image as well ,like this key : ['some string', ] but then I realized I could leverage the alt if this can be possible ?

```js
icons: { 
    iconA: <img style={imgStyle} alt='tool for food' src={iconA} />,
    iconB: <img style={imgStyle} alt='tool for drink' src={ iconB} />,
    }
    
    const convertedObject = useMemo(() => {
    return Object.entries(context.icons).map((e) => ({ equipment: e[1].alt  src: e[1] }));}, []);
```

Comment: Do you try to use getAttribute?

Comment: @АндрейБеспалов yes i am getting not that I am using ts as well Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'Element'

Comment: `e[1].props.alt` probably. Just look at what the value of `e[1]` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const convertedObject = useMemo(() => {
    return Object.entries(context.icons).map((e) => ({ 
        equipment: e[1].props.alt,
        src: e[1].props.src,
    }));
}, []);
```

Maybe you want to add "context.icons" to the useMemo dependecy list.

Comment: Could you please explain why did the props work ? I am clueless